# Summarized Data frame with conditional calculation. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to summarized Data frame with conditional calculation.

Based on col1 values find ratio for count of negatives of total count for it.

Example:

```
Col1    Col2  
--------------
 A       0.5
 A       0.3
 A      -0.6
 B      -0.3
 C      -0.2
 B         0
 C      -0.1


data = {'Col1':['A','A','A','B','C','B','C'],
        'Col2':[0.5,0.3,-0.6,-0.3,-0.2,0,-0.1]}

For A
Total number of negative (Count) / Total count for A 
= 1/3 = 0.33
```

Expected Result:

```
Col1    Col2  
--------------
 A       0.33
 B       0.5
 C       1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test negative values and aggregate `mean`, it working because `True`s are processing like `1`:

```
df1 = df['Col2'].lt(0).groupby(df['Col1']).mean().reset_index()
print (df1)
  Col1      Col2
0    A  0.333333
1    B  0.500000
2    C  1.000000
```

Solution with column filled by mask:

```
df1 = df.assign(Col2 = df['Col2'].lt(0)).groupby('Col1', as_index=False)['Col2'].mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution with np.where function:

```
df['Col3']=np.where(df['Col2']<0,1,0)
S=df.groupby('Col1')['Col3'].sum()/df.groupby('Col1')['Col3'].count()
print(S)

      Col1
A    0.333333
B    0.500000
C    1.000000
Name: Col3, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), which is a convenience feature (groupby is faster):

```
In [568]: pd.crosstab(index=df.Col1, 
                      columns=['Col2'], 
                      values = df.Col2.lt(0), 
                      aggfunc = 'mean')
Out[568]: 
col_0      Col2
Col1           
A      0.333333
B      0.500000
C      1.000000
```